# Why is it "thirteen" and not "threeteen"?

Tags: etymology, numbers

For example:

> fourteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen

These are all `number+teen`.

**What is wrong with threeteen and fiveteen?** Why are 13 and 15 written "differently"? Are they coming from `third+teen` and `fifth+teen`? If so, why 
were `d` and `h` removed? What is a "thir" and a "fift"?

I am utterly puzzled.

(not to mention eleven and twelve, which could have been oneteen and twoteen, but has been addressed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/why-do-eleven-and-twelve-get-unique-words-and-not-end-in-teen))

Comment: It's from Old English *thrēotīene* (see three, -teen). The spelling with initial thi- is recorded in late Middle English. Also, Middle English *thrittene*, from *thrittene*, adjective, from Old English *thrēotīne*; akin to Old English *tīen* ten

Comment: Do not ask *why* any words evolved thus; our forefathers spoke these words in certain ways which became a language, and it has come down to us in this form. It will change in future. Nobody held a conference in the year 1596 / 1796 / 1996 to formalise the words of the English language. In fact at least a few other languages seem to have undergone formal revisions but as @Hot Licks said, *this is English!*

Comment: If you expect consistency, surely it should be onety-one onety-two onety-three etc..?

Comment: Personally I think this is a fine question.  The question about eleven and twelve was on topic and highly upvoted, why shouldn't this be on topic as well?  It's probably a commonly searched question online, EL&U could provide an answer to those folks.

Comment: I'm wondering where the question about "thirdteen" and "fifthteen" come from. We don't say "sixthteen", etc. The slide from consonant to vowel in third and thirteen are parallel, and the retracted voicing in fifth and fifteen are parallel. It would help if luchonacho unpacked those questions a little.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=thirteen) is a good starting place to see where words come from. It's fairly common for sounds to change positions in a word; there's even a name for it, *metathesis*.

Comment: @JoelRees I was looking for some rationality that made 13 and 15 different, and using third+teen and fifth+teen kind of fitted, but removing the last letter of the adverb.

Comment: It's the same phenomenon that made *brid* evolve into *bird*, *hros* into *horse*, *aks* into *ask*. It's the same phenomenon that makes children say *spaghetti* as *pasketti* and the US President say *nuclear* as *nucular*. The name is metathesis, it very is common in all languages, well researched, and we have a dedicated tag for it. As to your actual question "why", as others have pointed out it makes little sense and is not really answerable, so I have to put it on hold as unclear. Please elaborate on what it is you wish to know. Who first did it? Why it caught on? Something else? Thanks.

Comment: [*Asterisk* vs *asteriks*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/10242/300), [*nuclear* vs *nucular*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/28847/300), [*ask* vs *aks*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/12082/300).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)#English

Comment: If you accept the concept of economy in pronunciation (saying it is hard or easy), "thr" is a harder pronunciation than "th(schwa)r", and "vt" is a harder pronunciation than "ft". Such difficult pronunciations are not part of the rest of the list. But there is no proof that that was the actual reason. And the known etymology indicates that it was at least a little more complicated than just that. Beyond that, we need someone who has done a graduate-level thesis in this specific question to chime in, and, so far, we have no takers.

Comment: Why is eleven not oneteen and twelve twoteen!

Comment: No no no. It's not "one-teen" and "two-teen". It's firsteen and seconteen. Then thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It has always seemed obvious to me: Three-teen and five-teen are harder to say than thirteen and fifteen. <strike>People are lazy.</strike>

The rest, <strike>laziness really doesn't make the pronunciation easier</strike> metathesis does not seem as natural.

(And, really, it would be the same with third and fifth. Try saying, once, tooth, threeth, fourth, fiveth.)

(afterthought)

Some people will note the middle English "fifthe", and object, but I'll point out that the cardinal is voiced as far back as middle English. You have to go back to old English to get an unvoiced "fif" as the cardinal number, and then you have to ask why middle English became voiced only in the cardinal.

It is true that the obvious always assumes the current context, but the current context is derived from the old context, and the principle of laziness applies in the old context at least as much as it applies now.

(end afterthought)

(second afterthought)

I am doing too much reading between the lines in the above.

Here is the entry for thirteen in the Online Etymology Dictionary:

[thirteen](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=thirteen)

Summary: it was spelled "thrittene" in Middle English, and shifted (metathesis) in the late 14th century. While the metathesis is recorded, the cause or reason is not. (How can we travel back in time and take a survey?)

Asserting laziness is probably oversimplifying. The impulse to change things for the sake of change is also a probable cause, and there are other known causes as well, such as linguistic fashion. Different people would have had different reasons, and the generalization of the metathesis is a statistical event, a "summation of many reasons.

So I'll apologize for asserting laziness.

[fifteen](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fifteen) and [five](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=five) in the Online Etymology Dictionary,

and [five](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/five) in Wiktionary

Note that five was *five* in Middle English, but *fif* in Old English. This is not metathesis, but the causes of the pronunciation change are not clearly stated in the above or anything else I have handy today. (I should check the Online Oxford, but it's one in the morning. I have other things I should be doing.)

(end second afterthought)

Comment: But what is "obvious"  is generally wrong.

Comment: Do you have a reference to show that the obvious is wrong in this case? If so, please post it.

Comment: Joel,  that is **not** how things work.  You have made a claim; it's up to you to validate it.  It is not up to the rest of us to invalidate it.   (See "god exists" for the usual example of your false logic)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Getting a little closer to definitive? ;-) I'm going to bed.