# When did the media start to pronounce 'nuclear' as 'nucular'?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I first noticed [George W.](https://www.georgewbush.com/) unable to pronounce the word *nuclear*, when he was in office. But now I am hearing *nucular* from various media commentators.

Was it 'W' who started it ?

[Note: I worked in the UK nuclear industry (making products for medical research and cancer treatment) from 1986 to 1994 and I never heard the word 'nucular' once.]

Comment: Related: [What causes the pronunciation “nucular”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28846)

Comment: @sumelic They discussed the pronunciation in that posting, indeed. But there was no conclusion regarding its usage and, most importantly, no mention of W !

Comment: You never heard Jimmy Carter pronounce it?

Comment: @HotLicks Was it all his fault, then ?

Comment: @NigelJ - I assume it's a Southern pronunciation.

Comment: @HotLicks And now we have Radio 4 newscasters using it in the UK.

Comment: What really gets to me is the fact that it is more difficult to say 'nucular'. It's clumsy.

Comment: President Eisenhower pronounced it "nucular", at least at times.

Comment: @Xanne: So did Dan Rather in the early 1970s on CBS TV. Rather was from Houston (as was Walter Cronkite, who said "nuclear"); Eisenhower was born in North Texas but grew up in Kansas. I grew up in South Texas among people who, for the most part, used the "nucular" option.

Comment: Which media are you referring to? British or American? The latter have been (mis)pronouncing nuclear à la  GW Bush mode for years.

Comment: Non-existant research and the link provided by the OP just directs visitors to George W Bush's website. So we know who we're talking I suppose.  At the very least a newspaper article noting the dialectal pronunciation, or even better, a YouTube link should be the thing to add. And some minimal research...

Comment: Agree with @Xanne ... President Eisenhower was the one who popularized this pronunciation in the US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [answers in the linked question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/28847/228732) provide a good analysis of how such a pronunciation might have developed.  There are [other sources with insight into that question as well.](https://books.google.com/books?id=9rJiC1gP_0wC&pg=PA139&dq=webster%27s%20dictionary%20of%20english%20usage%20%22nuclear%22%20pronunciation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQupy245nXAhVDQiYKHS1qDeUQ6AEIPjAE#v=onepage&q=webster's%20dictionary%20of%20english%20usage%20%22nuclear%22%20pronunciation&f=false)

As for **when**: The pronunciation /ˈn(j)ukjələr/ and in fact even the spelling "nucular" date back about as far as the term was widely used in the general public, in the mid-20th century.

The *OED* even provides a definition for the spelling:

> Alteration of nuclear *adj.*, representing a colloquial pronunciation (widely criticized by usage guides)

The earliest attested use, as mentioned, is as early as **1943** in printed form, though the citation is surprisingly not from a popular publication referring (as one might guess in the 1940s-'50s) to nuclear weapons, but rather is found in a scientific periodical.

> They..begin the reversion process which results in a 4n restitution nucleus... A **nucular** membrane begins to form around the whole group or around smaller groups or isolated chromosomes.

- Bulletin of the Torrey Botanical Club · *1870–*

*OED* notes that it *used to be* discouraged, but offers no judgment on the form:

> it is now commonly given as a variant in modern dictionaries. See Webster's Dict. Eng. Usage (1989) 673/1 for a discussion of possible origins of the pronunciation.

Comment: I shall have to stop being snooty about its usage, I guess.

Comment: There is an amusing instance in an editorial in the [Kent, Ohio] [_Daily Kent Stater_](https://dks.library.kent.edu/cgi-bin/kentstate?a=d&d=dks19541019-01.2.14&txq=nucular#) (October 19, 1954), a college newspaper: "The income from Princeton’s winning football season a few years back, helped keep Dr. Einstein and his staff of **nucular** physicists well equipped."